# postfix expand ldap group AND afterwards resolve alias

Tags: alias, postfix, group, ldap

We have a postfix server which has the user config stored in a openldap directory.

Recently we also implemented ldap groups which are expanded by postfix.
This works fine, unless the group expands to some email alias destinations.

All alias expanded from the group seem to not be resolved by the ldap alias database.

Any hints on how to have the ldap group expanding AND afterward pass these expanded groupmembers to the ldap alias resolving?

Our config looks like this:

In main.cf

```
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_expand_groups.cf,ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_accountsmap.cf,ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_expand_alias.cf
```

The ldap_expand_groups.cf

```
server_host = ldap://openldap1.server
version = 3
search_base = ou=groups,o=mailhosting
query_filter = (&(mail=%s)(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames))
leaf_result_attribute = mail
special_result_attribute = uniquemember
```

The ldap_expand_alias.cf

```
server_host =  ldap://openldap1.server
search_base = o=mailhosting
query_filter = (&(objectClass=MailAlias)(mail=%s)(accountActive=TRUE))
result_attribute = maildrop
bind = no
```